# Hardening Cisco router on Internet-MANAGEMENT PLANE

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, security

I need confirmation that I understood the Cisco manual right. So my network is like this:

```
ISP_RTR ---x.x.x.x/30--- Perimeter/Edge_RTR ---y.y.y.y/30--- FW1 --- DMZ1
                                            ---z.z.z.z/30--- FW2 --- DMZ2
```

Networks x.x.x.x/30, y.y.y.y/30, z.z.z.z/30, DMZ1 and DMZ2 are all with public IP addresses.

On my Perimeter/Edge router I need only console access.

So I configured commands:

```
#enable secret password
#service password-encryption
#no service tcp-small-servers
#no service udp-small-servers
#no ip finger
#no ip bootp server
#ip dhcp bootp ignore
#no service dhcp
#no ip domain-lookup
#no service pad
#no service config
#no cdp run
#no lldp run
#service tcp-keepalives-in
#service tcp-keepalives-out
#exception crashinfo maximum files 10
#no ip http server
#no ip http secure-server
#line aux 0
 #transport input none
 #transport output none
 #no exec
 #exec-timeout 0 1
 #no password
#line console 0
 #transport output none
#line vty 0 97
 #transport input none
 #transport output none
 #no exec
 #exec-timeout 0 1
 #no password
 #login
```

Commands that my IOS didn't have were:

```
#no mop enabled
#memory reserve console 4096
#exception memory ignore overflow io
#exception memory ignore overflow processor
#no vstack
```

I also buid ACL that should protect the router.

```
#ip access-list extended OUTSIDE
 !---Deny fragments to the infrastructure block
 #deny tcp any host x.x.x.x fragments
 #deny udp any host x.x.x.x fragments
 #deny icmp any host x.x.x.x fragments
 #deny ip any host x.x.x.x fragments
 #deny tcp any y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny udp any y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny icmp any y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny ip any y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny tcp any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny udp any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny icmp any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 fragments
 #deny ip any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 fragments
 !---Deny ip options
 #deny ip any any option any-options
 !---Deny/filter TTL value
 #deny ip any any ttl lt 5
 !---Anti-spoofing entries for RFC3330
 #deny ip host 0.0.0.0 any
 #deny ip 0.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 14.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 24.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 39.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 128.0.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
 #deny ip 169.254.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
 #deny ip 191.255.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
 #deny ip 192.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
 #deny ip 192.0.2.0 0.0.0.255 any
 #deny ip 192.88.99.0 0.0.0.255 any
 #deny ip 198.18.0.0 0.1.255.255 any
 #deny ip 223.255.255.0 0.0.0.255 any
 #deny ip 224.0.0.0 15.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 240.0.0.0 15.255.255.255 any
 !---Anti-spoofing entries for RFC1918
 #deny ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
 #deny ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 any
 #deny ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
 !---Anti-spoofing entries for my addresses as source
 #deny ip y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3 any
 #deny ip z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 any
 #deny ip dmz1-address dmz1-wildcard mask any
 #deny ip dmz2-address dmz2-wildcard mask any
 !---Deny access to infrastructure addresses (router interface and point-to-point links)
 #deny ip any host x.x.x.x
 #deny ip any y.y.y.y 0.0.0.3
 #deny ip any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3
 !---Permit transit traffic
 #permit ip any any
```

And applied ACL on to interface toward ISP router:

```
#interface ge 0/0
 #ip access-group OUTSIDE in
```

Did I miss something? Or did I put something too much?

Comment: re: `deny ip any z.z.z.z 0.0.0.3 fragments`, you probably don't want to restrict this to merely your /30 uplink... just use `deny ip any any fragments`

Comment: you might want to put a password on your vty and aux lines, even though  you don't use them.  Make it long.

Comment: Ron, but if there is no password configured on aux and vty lines, connections will be refused? Why is it better to configure the password?

Comment: Is it smart to have " #deny ip any any option any-options " enabled? Is there some legitimate traffic that use IP options? Or should I use selective drop?

Answer (score 2):

Best Cisco ASA FW Security Practice is to **Block Everything** and **Selectively Allow**...

Also-
Management Only Tracffic should not be used for or mixed with Normal Network Traffic; keep these Port Connections & Traffic Separated. This way if you get a security brach and you are not able to access the FW, you will still be able to access the Management Port and regain control.

Hope this helps...